# Implement Email Notification and let User know that someone answer on his/her post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Ok, so I am trying to implement notification system using `FluentEmail`

[FluentEmail](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail)

I have `HelpDesk` system and once `User` create post, Admin can see this post and answer. Once Admin Answer on post User should get notification to Email.
Currently I implement both side but the problem is that Email goes to wrong email address.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendDiscussionAsync(int ticketId, string message)
    {
        var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        var account = _db.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(userName));
        var userEmail = account == null ? string.Empty : account.Email;

        //var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
        //var account = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
        //var userEmail = account == null ? string.Empty : account.Email;


        var discussion = new Discussion
        {
            DateAndTime = DateTime.Now,
            Content = message,
            TicketId = ticketId,
            UserId = account.Id,
            ApplicationUser = account
        };

        var sender = new SmtpSender(() => new SmtpClient("localhost")
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailaddress", "password"),
            EnableSsl = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Port = 26,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        });

        Email.DefaultSender = sender;
        Email.DefaultRenderer = new RazorRenderer();

        var email = await Email
            .From("emailaddress")
            .To(userEmail)
            .Subject("Test Email for Notification")
            .Body(body: discussion.Content)
            .SendAsync();

        _unitOfwork.Discussion.Add(discussion);
        _unitOfwork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ticketId });
    }
```

I try in EmailService to pass Email Address to User how create the post, once User is logged in with UserName and Password. Right now the logic is opposite, once the Admin answer on post the email is automatically send to Admin Email Address, but it should sent to `User`
I get User loggin information here

```
 var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var account = _db.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(userName));
            var userEmail = account == null ? string.Empty : account.Email;
```

But I have no idea how to grab UserEmail and pass to `EmailService`. Here is my `Create` function of posts.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            if (ticketVM.Ticket.UserId > 0)
            {
                var usert = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == ticketVM.Ticket.UserId);
                ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = usert;
            }
            else
            {
                var usert = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);
                ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = usert;
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    //ticketVM.Ticket.Status = ((TicketStatus)Convert.ToInt32(ticketVM.Ticket.Status)).ToString();
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                    if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        ticketVM.Ticket.Status = "Otvoren";
                    }
                    else if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "2")
                    {
                        ticketVM.Ticket.Status = "NaCekanju";
                    }
                    else if (ticketVM.Ticket.Status.ToString() == "3")
                    {
                        ticketVM.Ticket.Status = "Zatvoren";
                    }
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                ticketVM.TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                });

                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id != 0)
                {
                    ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(ticketVM.Ticket.Id);
                }
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

Maybe this will also help you to get better understanding, I get UserInformation here, and this function contains `UserEmail`

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
        {
            var obj = _unitOfwork.ApplicationUser.GetAll(x => x.Name == name);
            return Json(new { data = obj });
        }
```

Here is my Ticket Model which containt user information `(UserId)` which is `ForeightKey` to ApplicationUser

```
public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kratak Opis")]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximalan broj karaktera je 20")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
        public string DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        //[Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka")]
        //public DateTime Answered { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta tiketa")]
        public int TicketTypeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TicketTypeID")]
        public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();

    }
```

Also ApplicationUser class

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ime")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Adresa")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Grad")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postanski broj")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        //[NotMapped]
        //public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain step by step and try to focus. Because it now seems like you expect to find the view model in the database.

Comment: What else do I need to explain ? I only need to grab user Email, user information from post. So If User with email address: `test@test.com` submit post, and admin with email address `admin@admin.com` replay to user post, User should get notification to email address . This information is store in `ticketVM.TIcket.ApplicationUser` which contain `Email` field. I need to take this email and store in to Email Service

Comment: @JHBonarius I update my question and I try to explain every details which I try and all code which I have

Comment: Aside from question, I hope that credentials you entered in code snippet are not production or any other system that being used. Please remove and change them immediately.

Comment: The data is not correct, it is fake data. But however I change it.

Comment: Code does not seems to doing what it explain in words. Like if Admin login then claim contains information related to that. Now if you want to send email to user who created post then you have to get that info from post and created user info and not the claim.

Comment: @dotnetstep Yes, exactly like this. But I have no idea how to get this information.

Comment: @Rayor If user post some comment on post then there is definitely relation between comment and post. When application post comment it should have post id along with it so  you can establish and retrieve all information related to that.

Comment: Everything I have alredy. Post Model, ApplicationUser but I have no idea how to grab User Infromation